# Why my detach() and delete() don't work?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I'm trying to delete some data from database

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('publications.destroy', $publication->id)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" dusk="btn-confirmDeletePub">Yes, Delete</button>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('publications','PublicationController');
```

Publication.php (Model)

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_publication');
}

public function topics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topic', 'topic_publication');
}

public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author', 'author_publication');
}

public function details()
{
        /*
        Since we must join the publications table with one of the
        journals/conference/editorship table (based on type column' value)
        to retrieve publication'details,  we "aggregate" the 3 alternatives in this method.

        this method is useful for retrieving from db, 
        for insertions, the 3 methods above ( journal(),conference(),editorship())
        should be used
        */
        switch ($this->type) {
            case 'journal':
                return $this->hasOne('App\Journal');
                break;

            case 'conference':
                return $this->hasOne('App\Conference');
                break;

            case 'editorship':
                return $this->hasOne('App\Editorship');
                break;

        }
 }
```

PublicationController.php

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $publication = Publication::find($id);
    $publication->users()->detach($publication->id);
    $publication->topics()->detach($publication->id);
    $publication->authors()->detach($publication->id);
    //dd($publication);
    $publication->details()->delete();

    //$publication->delete();

    //Redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Publication deleted correctly.');

    return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'Publication deleted correctly.');

}
```

When I click on the `Yes, Delete` button in the HTML form, it calls the `destroy` method in `PublicationController` to delete the Publication with the specific id. I tried to comment all the code and leave only the `return redirect` to see if the method is called, and it works.
After that, I removed the comments to the `detach()` functions, but inexplicably in the database they don't produce any results. Finally, I removed the comment at the `$publication->details()->delete();` and my application crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model doesn't know what the value of `$this->type` is?

I wouldn't recommend using a switch in a model. Model relationships are part of the boot sequence. You'll have to split it up into `journalDetails`, `conferenceDetails` and `editorshipDetails` and make the correct choice in the controllers.

```
public function journalDetails()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Journal');
}
public function conferenceDetails()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Conference');
}
public function editorshipDetails()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Editorship');
}
```

Comment: I already had these methods, except that I didn't add the word "details". After that I tried to do `$publication->Journal()->delete();` first, and then `$publication->Journal()->delete($publication->id);`, but neither worked